# Not able to fire click event programmatically

Tags: java, swing, instrumentation

I have below scenario and I am stuck at one place. Can anyone please help me on this?

I have a applet application which is deployed on `server1` and I am accessing this applet on `client1`. When I click on the any specific tab of `JTabbedPane`, request goes to server and it downloads specific classes which are required to load. When I click on any of the tab using Mouse everything works fine. When I do the same thing programmatically (dispatching `MouseEvent` or using `setSelectedIndex()` method of `JTabbedPane`), it doesnt work.

**Note:** My code of dispatching event is not on the same domain, I have this code locally only, Please read below for how I am dispatching the event.

I have created a java agent `MyAgent.jar` which includes a function to click on tab to select particular tab (`JTabbedPane`).

My java agent (instrumentation agent) is on `client1` and while running applet I am attaching my java agent with applet and this agent dispatches mouse click event. In this scenario, tab gets selected but it throws `ClassNotFoundException` and no components gets loaded in this tab because of the exception.

Anyone faced similar kind of issues or anyone aware of anything to tryout, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. The securityContext for javaAgent was different and the securityContext for applet was different. So javaAgent was not able to load the class which was present in applet context. Now I have make changes such that my code also runs in the applet context. Now when the event is fired it can load the required class.

Answer (score 2):

Rather then using a `MouseListener` to monitor changes to the tabbed state, you should be attaching `ChangeListener` to the selection model.

This way it won't matter how the tab is changed.

Comment: Hi, it is change listener only and tab gets selected. Issue is with downloading of classes that are required to load on tab click. When I do it programmatically, it doesnt download and load the required classes and gives ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: It should make no difference, but could you possibly post an example of the code, from the event trigger through the point where the code should be available...

Comment: I will not be able to give applet code here as it is not available for me as well. But I can provide you some more debuggin information I have with me. The same code works fine for jre version 1.6.21 or earlier and giving issue on later versions. The difference I can see is, `acc` (AccessControlContext) object is added in later versions in `AWTEvent` and I can see different values as well for acc object when dispatched programmatically and click manually by mouse. If any information regarding this then it would be helpful.

Comment: If the code is going through the same method, I can't see how the security manager would change

Comment: because initiater are different. When done programmatically, the code is present in "MyAgent.jar" which is on client side and if I click using Mouse, then request goes through one of the jar which was downloaded from the server where applet is deployed.

Comment: But in theory, all the code is executed on the client side JVM

Comment: Yes, that is why I am also confused and not sure what I have to do to solve the issue.

Comment: It could be an issue with the class loader

Comment: if it is issue with classLoader how do I go about it to resolve. Note: I dont have any control over applet application, I just have control on "MyAgent.jar" instrumentation agent.

Comment: In that case, I don't think you can.  You could try signing the Jar (not sure how you would go about it), but unless the client side is going to allow you to run code within it's sandbox, there's nothing you can do.  That's the point of the security model.